# How can I get the handle to the property sheet in CPrintDialogEx

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to add a property page to `CPrintDialogEx` and failing miserably. My code currently is

```
PROPSHEETPAGE optionsPage1;
HPROPSHEETPAGE hOptionsPage = NULL;

memset(&optionsPage1, 0, sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE));
optionsPage1.dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE);
optionsPage1.dwFlags = PSP_DEFAULT | PSP_USETITLE;
optionsPage1.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
optionsPage1.pszTemplate = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_QUICKREPORT_OPTIONS);
optionsPage1.hIcon = NULL;
optionsPage1.pszIcon = NULL;
optionsPage1.pszTitle = _T("Options");
optionsPage1.pfnDlgProc = (DLGPROC)CQuickReport::OptionsPropertyPageDlgProc;
optionsPage1.lParam = NULL;
m_pdex.nPropertyPages = 1;
hOptionsPage = CreatePropertySheetPage(&optionsPage1);
m_pdex.lphPropertyPages = &hOptionsPage;

INT_PTR nResult = CPrintDialogEx::DoModal();
```

The property page is NOT showing, so I want to add it after `WM_INITDIALOG` in `CPrintDialogEx`.  How can I get the handle to the property sheet after it's created.  If somebody has a valiant way to make this work and title the `CPrintDialogEx` outside of setting the txt of the grandparent to the dialog in `OnInitDialog`

Comment: Show the definition for `OptionsPropertyPageDlgProc`

Comment: how do I add the DlgProc.  It's complining I am 327 characters overlimit!

Comment: Click the edit button and make changes to your question. If you have a DLL, it depends on where `IDD_QUICKREPORT_OPTIONS` is located. You get 1814 error if looking in the wrong place for resource.

Comment: @user9778277 I think you're trying to add it as a comment which has a character limit. But you're being asked to edit the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property sheet should be added before calling `DoModal`.

`OnInitDialog` is called after `DoModal`, so it is too late to initialize the page.

Simply override `DoModal` instead:

```
class CMyPrintDialogEx : public CPrintDialogEx
{
public:
    INT_PTR DoModal()
    {
        PROPSHEETPAGE optionsPage1;
        memset(&optionsPage1, 0, sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE));
        optionsPage1.dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE);
        optionsPage1.dwFlags = PSP_DEFAULT | PSP_USETITLE;
        optionsPage1.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
        optionsPage1.pszTemplate = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_QUICKREPORT_OPTIONS);
        optionsPage1.pszTitle = _T("Options");
        optionsPage1.pfnDlgProc = (DLGPROC)CQuickReport::OptionsPropertyPageDlgProc;
        optionsPage1.lParam = NULL;
        m_pdex.nPropertyPages = 1;
        HPROPSHEETPAGE hOptionsPage = CreatePropertySheetPage(&optionsPage1);
        m_pdex.lphPropertyPages = &hOptionsPage;

        INT_PTR nResult = CPrintDialogEx::DoModal();

        return nResult;
    }
};
```

Comment: @user9778277 Barmak asked you to supply the definition of cquickreport::OptionsPropertyPageDlgProc. Please update your question and provide enough context to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: LRESULT CQuickReport::OptionsPropertyPageDlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

Comment: You have shown the declaration of the function, this does not contain any surprises and will not reproduce any error.

Comment: I have to also add it DID work before I moved everything into a DLL.

Comment: Sorry Barmak.  When you asked for the definition I was asleep.  I'm debugging and now realize by trying to use ::DialogBox to display the would be property page as a dialog tht it immediately returns -1 and GetLastError() returns 1814.  The resource IS in the DLL.

Comment: I limited the DlgProc for testing

Comment: INT_PTR nResult = ::DialogBox(::AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_QUICKREPORT_OPTIONS), AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd, (DLGPROC)CQuickReport::OptionsPropertyPageDlgProc);
 DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();

Comment: Don't add random code in the comment section. Edit your question instead. Your `IDD_QUICKREPORT_OPTIONS` resource can be stored in DLL or EXE file. In your case it is stored in the wrong place and causing 1814 error.

Comment: I fixed the issue by saving the hInstance handle in DLLMain and passing THAT value to create the page.  It works.  How do I upvote you?